# Sonos 3rd Party App on different Wifi than Household

Tags: sonos

In the Sonos API reference documentation there is an example  for how to allow the user to select a household in case multiple households are associated with the connected user account
https://developer.sonos.com/build/seg/discover/
In the Sample Screenshot at the bottom, the text says "*Make sure that this device and the Sonos system are on the same WiFi network.*"

1. Am I correct to assume this is only a recommendation and not a requirement?
2. The Sonos API is cloud based, so I would assume it does not matter if the device and the Sonos system are connected to the same Wifi Network?
3. Also, using the Sonos API, would there even be a way to determine to which WiFi network the Sonos System is connected?
4. Does the Household ID contain any information about the WiFi SSID?

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Am I correct to assume this is only a recommendation and not a requirement?

This is correct, this is a recommendation, with regards to discovery. More broadly, however, if you want to have a Sonos speaker interact with a specific Sonos system, it has to be on the same network. For instance, all speakers in a single household should be on the same network.

> 2. The Sonos API is cloud based, so I would assume it does not matter if the device and the Sonos system are connected to the same Wifi Network?

Your assumption is correct; since the Sonos API is cloud-based, you can access and control the Sonos system regardless of what network you are on.

> 3. Also, using the Sonos API, would there even be a way to determine to which WiFi network the Sonos System is connected?
> 4. Does the Household ID contain any information about the WiFi SSID?

No, there currently is not any way to get information regarding the WiFi SSID using the Sonos API nor Household ID.

---

For more on Discovery, see https://developer.sonos.com/build/direct-control/discover/.